# @ColumnTransformer have no alias when select column

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I need encrypted and decrypted some column such.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
@Data
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", columnDefinition = "varchar")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "pgp_sym_decrypt(decode(NAME, 'hex'), 'key')", write = "encode(pgp_sym_encrypt(?, 'key'), 'hex')")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Person parent;

}
```

When I use PersonRepository.findOneByParentId(10L); and see log sql is

```
    select
        person0_."id" as id1_99_,
        pgp_sym_decrypt(decode(NAME, 'hex'), 'key') as name2_99_
    from
        "public"."person" person0_
    left outer join
        "public"."person" person1_
            on person0_."parent_id"=person1_."id" 
    where
        person1_."id"=?
```

This error message

```
ERROR: column reference "name" is ambiguous
```

Why **@ColumnTransformer** don't add table alias of column "name", **What should I do ?**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and adding the forColumn property worked for me.

@ColumnTransformer(
forColumn = "lastName",

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30121461)

Comment: The clue was indeed correct. In my example the org_id was ambigous. 

I have added the forColumn defining the two columns responsible for the parameters of the SQL function:

`@ColumnTransformer(forColumn = "internalReferenceNumber ,organization", read = "calc_closure_date(internal_reference_number, org_id)")`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to giving allias to each column in front,You have to give allias while giving column name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).